# Input file not recognized in hadoop jar command

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, ubuntu-14.04, ioexception

```
WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: File /usr/hdfs/Deliverydetails.txt does not exist.
at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.validateFiles(GenericOptionsParser.java:397)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.processGeneralOptions(GenericOptionsParser.java:301)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.parseGeneralOptions(GenericOptionsParser.java:431)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.<init>(GenericOptionsParser.java:170)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.<init>(GenericOptionsParser.java:153)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:64)
at SmsDriver.main(SmsDriver.java:44)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
```

This is the error I have been getting while running the hadoop jar command though the input file is existing in that path which I checked in the browser.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Relevant source code?  A small piece of demo code that can reproduce the problem would be best.

Comment: This is the actual program which I compiled and created a jar file with the name SmsDriver and after hadoop jar command this is what i got as output http://kickstarthadoop.blogspot.in/2011/09/joins-with-plain-map-reduce.html

Comment: Which is the user running the MR job?

Comment: The only hduser is running the main file SmsDriver

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that /usr/hdfs/ is the HDFS file path and not local filesystem path.

Comment: It is the HDFS file path only not the local file system path. The file is also residing in the HDFS filepath

Comment: So I hope, in place of input locations you haven't provided the full path with file names and instead Provided the input directories.

Comment: No actually it didn't give permissions to create input directory in the HDFS filepath so tried to place only those 3 input files in the directory and tried. Also tried with file paths but both didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Try doing hadoop fs -ls /usr/hdfs/Deliverydetails.txt 
If it doesn't exist, then your file is present in local filesystem instead of hadoop filesystem

Comment: It is present in the hadoop file system. After the above command this was the output Found 1 items
-rw-r--r--   1 hduser supergroup         54 2015-04-24 11:58 /usr/hdfs/Deliverydetails.txt

Comment: Can you try changing the permission of this hadoop file. Use this command hadoop fs -chmod  777 /usr/hdfs/Deliverydetails.txt. Sometimes this could be the issue that user faces.

Comment: Are you passing the input filepath as an argument or through your driver class.  And it would be helpful if you could paste your driver class code here for reference .

Comment: Yes Passing the input as an argument and here is the driver code public class SmsDriver extends Configured implements Tool
{
       public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
              JobConf conf = new JobConf(getConf(), SmsDriver.class);
              conf.setJobName("SMS Reports");
              conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
              conf.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
              conf.setReducerClass(SmsReducer.class);

Comment: MultipleInputs.addInputPath(conf, new Path(args[0]), TextInputFormat.class, UserFileMapper.class);
              MultipleInputs.addInputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]), TextInputFormat.class, DeliveryFileMapper.class);
              FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[2]));
              JobClient.runJob(conf);
              return 0;
       }
       public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
              int res = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new SmsDriver(),args);
              System.exit(res);
       }
}

Comment: sry code exceeded the number of characters per comment so posted in two comments

Comment: Why passing MultipleInputs.addInputPath, put all the files that you want as an input file in a directory and give the path as an input directory like eg : conf.setInputPath(new Path("input"));

Comment: And now pass /usr/hdfs/input as an argument for input file. Hadoop will take all the files in your input directory and process it.

Comment: This is the code which takes the input files and input is specific to each  class how do I set it statically.
MultipleInputs.addInputPath(conf, new Path(args[0]), TextInputFormat.class, UserFileMapper.class);
MultipleInputs.addInputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]), TextInputFormat.class, DeliveryFileMapper.class);